# Make a service on Android which implements broadcast reciever?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I am making an application which receives SMS; I need a service which implements a broadcast receiver. This service should be called from an activity. When a particular type of SMS comes in, this service catches it and responds to its parent activity.
Somebody, please help me; how do I code it? Can any one please send me code, or tips to write it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not required that the broadcast receiver for SMS is included in a server. You can setup the receiver using just AndroidManifest.xml and a BroadcastReceiver class

The is no "parent" activity associated with services.

You will need to specify the following in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
</uses-permission>
```

You can specify a receiver in the manifest as well and add the following intent filter.

```
<intent-filter>
           <action android:value="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: ya i have don it in this way but just wana service so it can listen on very time

Comment: so please help me to make a service and broadcast receiver in it

Comment: i knw tat it is listening while my activity is runing but when i close my activity broadcast closed so iam wana a service which always runs